# png loses alpha on gltf export

Tags: gltf

I was trying out the gltf + bin + texture export feature on blender 2.8.

and the model i was exporting had a png eye texture with a transparent background.
[image: eye1]

with a Principled BSDF shader like this, which worked fine.

[image: node1]

but when I exported the model to gltf then reimported it,

the png texture file turned to this:

[image: eye2]

and the nodes like this: 
[image: node2]
the alpha line disconnected

so, I was wondering if the gltf format doesn't support transparent textures,
or is there something wrong with what I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is a known bug, a regression.  Issue [#425](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/425) details it, and a fix is in the works in [#506](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/pull/506).  Sometime in the next few days it should start working again, after that PR gets merged.

Also, even after the missing alpha channel gets fixed, you'll still have to specifically enable blending mode per-material.  This is done in the "Settings" panel of an Eevee material, "Blend Mode" should be set to "Alpha Blend".

Answer (score 0):

Try export with transparent JPEGS

[image]